# HERE Maps REST API transactions limit freemium

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

anybody knows, can I get all my 250K REST API transactions in one day in HERE Maps? (Freemium account allows 250K pro month). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can. But practically if you try it ,you may not be able to do it as most services will flag such high volumes of request as a dos attack and may blacklist your ip.